# Py-Game Connect4 - Minimax (Program Halting Recursively)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, pygame, minimax

main.py

```
from Player import Player

import tkinter as tk
import pygame
import pygame_menu
import time
import colors
import Connect4 as cFour
import Minimax as mx


def text_format(option, textSize, textColor):
    """
    Creates a text object to show in the main menu
    """
    newFont = pygame.font.Font(pygame_menu.font.FONT_FRANCHISE, textSize)
    newText = newFont.render(option, 0, textColor)
    return newText

def load_screen():
    """
    This initializes the window for pygame to use
    """
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Connect4")
    return screen

def get_player_details(screen):
    """
    Creates a tkinter object(button) that gets players names
    """
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Player Names!")

    tk.Label(root, text="Player One", fg="blue").grid(row=0)
    tk.Label(root, text="Player Two", fg="red").grid(row=1)

    p1 = tk.Entry(root, font=(None, 15))
    p2 = tk.Entry(root, font=(None, 15))

    p1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    p2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    tk.Button(root, text='Play!', command= lambda: play_game(p1.get(),p2.get(), root, screen)).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
    tk.mainloop()
    
def get_player_ai_details(screen):
    """
    Creating the panel to allow the user to select a color and go against the AI
    """
    options = ["Player 1", "Player 2"]
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Player 1(Blue) or 2(Red)?")

    colorChoice= tk.StringVar(root)
    colorChoice.set(options[0])

    tk.OptionMenu(root, colorChoice, *options).grid(row=3)

    p1 = tk.Entry(root, font=(None, 15))
    p1.grid(row=3, column=1)

    tk.Button(root, text="Play Computer!", command=lambda: play_computer(colorChoice.get(), p1.get(), root, screen)).grid(row=10, column=1)
    
    tk.mainloop()

def play_computer(colorChoice, playerName, root, screen):
    """
    Connect4 play function (human v computer)
    """
    root.destroy()

    if colorChoice == "Player 1":
        mx.Minimax(Player(playerName), Player("Ed"), screen).play_computer()
    else:
        mx.Minimax(Player("Ed"), Player(playerName), screen).play_computer()
    
def play_game(p1Name, p2Name, root, screen):
    """
    Connect4 play function (human v human)
    """
    root.destroy()
    game = cFour.Connect4(Player(p1Name.strip()), Player(p2Name.strip()), screen).play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = load_screen()

    features = [
        ("Player Vs Player", colors.yellow),
        ("Player Vs AI", colors.red),
        ("Quit", colors.gray)
    ]

    iterator = 0
    menu = True
    while menu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            #This if block makes it where the user doesnt have to click arrow key up/down if they have exhausted the possible options, it will loop you throughout options
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    iterator += 1
                    if iterator == len(features):
                        iterator = 0

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    iterator -= 1
                    if iterator < 0:
                        iterator = len(features) - 1

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if selected == "Player Vs Player":
                        get_player_details(screen)
                    if selected == "Player Vs AI":
                        get_player_ai_details(screen)
                    if selected == "Quit":
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
            selected = features[iterator][0]
                
        screen.fill(colors.blue)
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        for i in range(0, len(features)):
            counter = -50 + (i * 90) # Equation that sets distance between each choice in main menu
            if i == iterator:
                text = text_format(features[i][0], 80, features[i][1])
            else:
                text = text_format(features[i][0], 80, colors.black)
            player_rect = text.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)
            player_rect[1] = player_rect[1] + counter
            screen.blit(text, player_rect)    
        pygame.display.update()
```

Connect4.py

```
import pygame
import colors
import tkinter as tk
import pygame_menu
# import pandas as pd
import random

class Connect4:
    """
    Class used to represent connect4 game
    """
    def __init__(self, player1, player2, screen):

        # Use 1 version of the screen instead of trying to create a new one
        self.screen = screen

        # Circle Radius and Width
        self.WIDTH = 0
        self.CIRCLERADIUS = 25

        # Game-Time Variables
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.moveNumber = 0
        self.gameOver = False
        self.COLUMNS = 7
        self.ROWS = 6
        self.EMPTY = 99
        self.board = [[self.EMPTY for x in range(self.COLUMNS)] for y in range(self.ROWS)]

        # The distance between where the window starts and the game board is placed
        self.DISTANCE = 90

        # Space between each circle
        self.DISTANCEGAP = 70

        # Setting rectangle default       
        self.LEFT = 50
        self.TOP = 70
        self.HEIGHT = 470
        self.RECWIDTH = 500

        #Creating new tkinterobject
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.scoreboard = {self.player1.name: 0, self.player2.name: 0, "ties": 0}
        
        # Storing locations of available moves given a user clicks the window -- Tuple of locations
        self.POSITIONS = [
            (
                self.DISTANCE + (self.DISTANCEGAP*column) - self.CIRCLERADIUS,
                self.DISTANCE + (self.DISTANCEGAP*column) + self.CIRCLERADIUS
            )
            for column in range(0, self.COLUMNS)
        ] 

    def who_won(self, board, piece):
        """
        Determines the state of the game and finds if there is a winner
        """
        # Horizontal
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS - 3):
            for row in range(0, self.ROWS):
                if board[row][col] == piece and board[row][col + 1] == piece and board[row][col + 2] == piece and board[row][col + 3] == piece:
                    return True

        # Vertical
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
            for row in range(0, self.ROWS - 3):
                if board[row][col] == piece and board[row + 1][col] == piece and board[row + 2][col] == piece and board[row + 3][col] == piece:
                    return True
                
        # Up-Left/Down-Right
        for col in range(3, self.COLUMNS):
            for row in range(3, self.ROWS):
                if board[row][col] == piece and board[row - 1][col - 1] == piece and board[row - 2][col - 2] == piece and board[row - 3][col - 3] == piece:
                    return True
        
        # Up-Right/Down-Left
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS - 3):
            for row in range(3, self.ROWS):
                if board[row][col] == piece and board[row - 1][col + 1] == piece and board[row - 2][col + 2] == piece and board[row - 3][col + 3] == piece:
                    return True
        
        # A winning move is not found
        return False

    def is_legal_move(self, position, board):
        """
        Validates if a move is available/legal
        """
        if board[0][position] == self.EMPTY:
            return True
        return False

    def display_board(self):
        """
        Displaying the game board to the user
        """
        # Function: rect(surface, color, rectangle object, optional width) -- First one forms the outline of the board
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, colors.salmon, (self.LEFT, self.TOP, self.RECWIDTH, self.HEIGHT), 13)

        # This forms inner-most rectangle that users play on
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, colors.burlywood, (self.LEFT, self.TOP, self.RECWIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
        
        for column in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
            colEq = self.DISTANCE + (self.DISTANCEGAP * column)
            for row in range(0, self.ROWS):
                # 125 is used here to make a the board placed in the center of the board and helps finding a value for self.TOP easier
                rowEq = 125 + (self.DISTANCEGAP * row)
                if self.board[row][column] == self.EMPTY:
                    color = colors.white
                elif self.board[row][column] == 0:
                    color = colors.realBlue
                elif self.board[row][column] == 1:
                    color = colors.red
                pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, color, (colEq, rowEq), self.CIRCLERADIUS, self.WIDTH)
        pygame.display.flip()
    
    def play(self):
        """
        This is the game-loop
        """
        while not self.gameOver:
            self.display_board()
            if self.moveNumber % 2 == 0:
                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(self.player1.name, colors.realBlue)
            elif self.moveNumber % 2 == 1:
                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(self.player2.name, colors.red)
            self.screen.blit(userText, userRect) 

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.screen.fill(colors.aquamarine) # Set up background color
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                    self.gameOver = True 
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    position = self.get_column_position(x)
                    if self.moveNumber % 2 == 0 and position != self.EMPTY:
                        if self.is_legal_move(position, self.board):                            
                            self.drop_piece_animation(position)
                            if self.who_won(self.board, 0):
                                self.gameOver = True
                                self.scoreboard[self.player1.name] = self.scoreboard.get(self.player1.name) + 1
                                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(self.player1.name + " " + "Wins!!!", colors.dark_gray)
                            elif self.check_if_tie(self.board):
                                self.gameOver = True
                                self.scoreboard["ties"] = self.scoreboard.get("ties") + 1
                                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name("It is a TIE!!!", colors.dark_gray)

                    elif self.moveNumber % 2 == 1 and position != self.EMPTY:
                        if self.is_legal_move(position, self.board):                            
                            self.drop_piece_animation(position)
                            if self.who_won(self.board, 1):
                                self.gameOver = True
                                self.scoreboard[self.player2.name] = self.scoreboard.get(self.player2.name) + 1
                                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(self.player2.name + " " + "Wins!!!", colors.dark_gray)
                            elif self.check_if_tie(self.board):
                                self.gameOver = True
                                self.scoreboard["ties"] = self.scoreboard.get("ties") + 1
                                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name("It is a TIE!!!", colors.dark_gray)
        self.display_board()
        self.screen.blit(userText, userRect) 
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.display_scoreboard(False)
            
    def display_scoreboard(self, isAi):
        """
        This enables the tkinter object so I can display the user options after : Victory/Loss/Tie
        """
        self.root.geometry('460x150+300+0')
        self.reset()
        self.root.title("Choices")

        # This creates the feedback information screen that the user sees after a game
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Close window to go to main menu", font=(None, 15, 'underline'), anchor='w', justify='left').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Label(self.root, text=self.player1.name + ": " + str(self.scoreboard.get(self.player1.name)), font=(None, 15), anchor='w', justify='left').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky = "NSEW")
        tk.Label(self.root, text=self.player2.name + ": " + str(self.scoreboard.get(self.player2.name)), font=(None, 15), anchor='w', justify='left').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NSEW")
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Ties: " + str(self.scoreboard.get("ties")), font=(None, 15), anchor='w', justify='left').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

        # if isAi == True:
        #     # tk.Button(self.root, text='Rematch!', command=self.playAi, font=(None, 12), fg="blue").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        # else:
        tk.Button(self.root, text='Rematch!', command=self.play, font=(None, 12), fg="blue").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        
        # tk.Button(self.root, text='Rematch with Swap!', command= lambda: self.swapPlayers(isAi), font=(None, 12), fg="red").grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

        tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def check_if_tie(self, board):
        """
        A possible game state : Checking for a tie
        """
        totalPieces = 0
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
            for row in range(0, self.ROWS):
                if board[row][col] == 0 or board[row][col] == 1:
                    totalPieces += 1  
        if totalPieces == 42:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def display_player_name(self, name, color):
        """
        A feature to help users know who's turn it is that gets displayed
        """
        font = pygame.font.Font(pygame_menu.font.FONT_FRANCHISE, 60) 
        text = font.render(name, True, color)
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (len(name) * 30, 20)
        return text, textRect

    def drop_piece_animation(self, position):
        """
        Inserting a piece at a given position with the animation of a piece drop
        """
        tmpRow = 5
        while self.board[tmpRow][position] == 1 or self.board[tmpRow][position] == 0:
            tmpRow -= 1

        for i in range(0, tmpRow + 1):
            self.board[i][position] = self.moveNumber % 2
            self.display_board()
            pygame.time.delay(200)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.board[i][position] = self.EMPTY

        self.board[tmpRow][position] = self.moveNumber % 2
        self.moveNumber += 1

    def get_column_position(self, position):
        """
        Takes a X coordinate value dependent on a click and determines what column user clicked
        """
        index = 0
        for i in self.POSITIONS:
            if position + self.CIRCLERADIUS/2 >= i[0] and position - self.CIRCLERADIUS/2 <= i[1]:
                return index
            index += 1
        return self.EMPTY

    def reset(self):
        """
        Restoring the game in its original state
        """
        self.moveNumber = 0
        self.board = [[self.EMPTY for x in range(self.COLUMNS)] for y in range(self.ROWS)]
        self.gameOver = False
    
    def play_computer(self):
        """
        This is the game-loop used for AI play
        """
        # If/else block to distinguish the human/Ai because the ai cant mouse click events
        if self.player1.name == "Ed": # Ed Watkins (Staten Island)
            humanPlayer = 1
            computerPlayer = 0

            humanName = self.player2.name
            computerName = self.player1.name

        elif self.player2.name == "Ed":
            humanPlayer = 0
            computerPlayer = 1

            humanName = self.player1.name
            computerName = self.player2.name
            
        while not self.gameOver:
            self.display_board()
            if self.moveNumber % 2 == 0:
                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(self.player1.name, colors.blue)
            elif self.moveNumber % 2 == 1:
                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(self.player2.name, colors.red)
            self.screen.blit(userText, userRect) 

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.screen.fill(colors.aquamarine) # Set up background color
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                    self.gameOver = True 
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    position = self.get_column_position(x)
                    if self.moveNumber % 2 == humanPlayer and position != self.EMPTY:
                        if self.is_legal_move(position, self.board):                            
                            self.drop_piece_animation(position)
                            if self.who_won(self.board, humanPlayer):
                                self.gameOver = True
                                self.scoreboard[humanName] = self.scoreboard.get(humanName) + 1
                                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(humanName + " " + "Wins!!!", colors.dark_gray)
                            elif self.check_if_tie(self.board):
                                self.gameOver = True
                                self.scoreboard["ties"] = self.scoreboard.get("ties") + 1
                                userText, userRect = self.display_player_name("It is a TIE!!!", colors.dark_gray)
            if self.moveNumber % 2 == computerPlayer and self.gameOver == False:
                move = self.generate_move(self.board, 4, computerPlayer, humanPlayer, True, self.moveNumber)
                self.drop_piece_animation(move)
                if self.who_won(self.board, computerPlayer):
                    self.gameOver = True
                    self.scoreboard[computerName] = self.scoreboard.get(computerName) + 1
                    userText, userRect = self.display_player_name(computerName + " " + "Wins!!!", colors.dark_gray)
                elif self.check_if_tie(self.board):
                    self.gameOver = True
                    self.scoreboard["ties"] = self.scoreboard.get("ties") + 1
                    userText, userRect = self.display_player_name("It is a TIE!!!", colors.dark_gray)

        self.display_board()
        self.screen.blit(userText, userRect) 
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Minimax.py

```
from Connect4 import Connect4
import random
from copy import copy, deepcopy
import pygame

class Minimax(Connect4):
    def __init__(self, player1, player2, screen):
        super().__init__(player1, player2, screen)
    
    def is_game_over(self, board):
        if self.who_won(board, 1) or self.who_won(board, 0):
            return True
        return False

    def generate_move(self, board, depth, computerPlayer, humanPlayer, maximizingPlayer, moveNumber):
        if depth == 0 or self.is_game_over(board) or self.check_if_tie(board):
            if self.is_game_over(board):
                if self.who_won(board, computerPlayer):
                    return 1000000
                elif self.who_won(board, humanPlayer):
                    return -1000000
                elif self.check_if_tie(board):
                    return 0
            else:
                return self.get_game_score(board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer)

        if maximizingPlayer:
            maxValue = -1000000
            for move in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
                tmpBoard = self.copyBoard(board)
                if self.is_legal_move(move, tmpBoard):
                    self.drop_piece_computer(move, tmpBoard, moveNumber)
                    result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, computerPlayer, humanPlayer, False, moveNumber + 1)
                    if result >= maxValue:
                        maxValue = result
                        bestMove = move
            return bestMove
        else:
            minValue = 1000000
            for move in range(0,self.COLUMNS):
                tmpBoard = self.copyBoard(board)
                if self.is_legal_move(move, tmpBoard):
                    self.drop_piece_computer(move, tmpBoard, moveNumber)
                    result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, humanPlayer, humanPlayer, True, moveNumber + 1)
                    if result <= minValue:
                        minValue = result
                        thismove = move
            return thismove

    def copyBoard(self, board):
        tmpList = [[self.EMPTY for x in range(self.COLUMNS)] for y in range(self.ROWS)]
        for row in range(0, self.ROWS):
            for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
                tmpList[row][col] = board[row][col]
        
        return tmpList

    def drop_piece_computer(self, position, board, moveNumber):
        """
        Inserting a piece at a given position with the animation of a piece drop
        """
        tmpRow = 5
        while board[tmpRow][position] == 1 or board[tmpRow][position] == 0:
            tmpRow -= 1

        
        board[tmpRow][position] = moveNumber % 2
        # moveNumber += 1

    def get_game_score(self, board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer):
        totalScore = 0
        totalScore += self.get_hori_score(board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer)
        # totalScore += self.get_vert_score(board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer)
        # totalScore += self.get_upright_score(board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer)
        # totalScore += self.get_upleft_score(board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer)

        return totalScore

    def get_hori_score(self, board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer):
        score = 0
        # List to collect all the groupings of 4(Horizontally) out of the current game state
        groupingFourList = []
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS - 3):
            for row in range(0, self.ROWS):
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col + 1])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col + 2])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col + 3])

                computerPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, 1)
                humanPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, 0)
                emptyPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, self.EMPTY)

                score += self.score_metric(computerPieces, humanPieces, emptyPieces)
                groupingFourList = []
        
        return score

    def get_upright_score(self, board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer):
        score = 0
        # List to collect all the groupings of 4(Horizontally) out of the current game state
        groupingFourList = []
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS - 3):
            for row in range(3, self.ROWS):
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row - 1][col + 1])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row - 2][col + 2])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row - 3][col + 3])

                computerPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, 1)
                humanPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, 0)
                emptyPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, self.EMPTY)

                score += self.score_metric(computerPieces, humanPieces, emptyPieces)
                groupingFourList = []
        
        return score

    def get_upleft_score(self, board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer):
        score = 0
        # List to collect all the groupings of 4(Horizontally) out of the current game state
        groupingFourList = []
        for col in range(3, self.COLUMNS):
            for row in range(3, self.ROWS):
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row - 1][col - 1])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row - 2][col - 2])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row - 3][col - 3])

                computerPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, 1)
                humanPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, humanPlayer)
                emptyPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, self.EMPTY)

                score += self.score_metric(computerPieces, humanPieces, emptyPieces)
                groupingFourList = []
        
        return score

    def get_vert_score(self, board, computerPlayer, humanPlayer):
        score = 0
        # List to collect all the groupings of 4(Horizontally) out of the current game state
        groupingFourList = []
        for col in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
            for row in range(0, self.ROWS -3):
                groupingFourList.append(board[row][col])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row + 1][col])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row + 2][col])
                groupingFourList.append(board[row + 3][col])

                computerPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, computerPlayer)
                humanPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, humanPlayer)
                emptyPieces = self.count_player_pieces(groupingFourList, self.EMPTY)

                score += self.score_metric(computerPieces, humanPieces, emptyPieces)
                groupingFourList = []
        
        return score

    def count_player_pieces(self, groupingFourList, playerPiece):
        totalPieces = 0

        for piece in groupingFourList:
            if piece == playerPiece:
                totalPieces += 1
        
        return totalPieces

    def score_metric(self, computerPieces, humanPieces, emptyPieces):
        score = 0

        # Making bot prioritize playing defense than offense
        # Thats why the score is lower when regarding the enemy: AI chooses highest scoring move
        if (computerPieces == 4):
            score += 100
        elif (computerPieces == 3 and emptyPieces == 1):
            score += 20
        elif (computerPieces == 2 and emptyPieces == 2):
            score += 10
        if (humanPieces == 3 and emptyPieces == 1):
            score -= 100

        return score
```

colors.py

```
"""
Valid colors to use got it from this link : https://python-forum.io/Thread-PyGame-PyGame-Colors
"""
realBlue = (0,0,255)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
orange = (255,100,10)
blue_green = (0,255,170)
marroon = (115,0,0)
lime = (180,255,100)
pink = (255,100,180)
purple = (240,0,255)
magenta = (255,0,230)
brown = (100,40,0)
forest_green = (0,50,0)
navy_blue = (0,0,100)
rust = (210,150,75)
dandilion_yellow = (255,200,0)
highlighter = (255,255,100)
sky_blue = (0,255,255)
light_gray = (200,200,200)
dark_gray = (50,50,50)
tan = (230,220,170)
coffee_brown = (200,190,140)
moon_glow = (235, 245, 255)
burlywood = (255, 211, 155)
salmon = (139, 76, 57)
aquamarine = (127, 255, 212)

#Colors used for menu
blue = (135, 206, 250)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
red = (255,0,0)
gray = (128, 128, 128)
```

Player.py

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

The solution is solved but stackoverflow wont allow me to remove the question. The reason I would like the question removed because the answer provided isnt the solution so it would just throw other people off.

Comment: @rabbid76 so you want me to tell you what the fix was but make it an answer?

Comment: @Rabbid76 hopefully that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution is as follows:

In this section of code this is going through a portion of the search space and evaluating the game states based on the best moves for each player. Through this algorithm the AI knows the best moves for each player and can make a "good" move.

```
        if maximizingPlayer:
            maxValue = -1000000
            for move in range(0, self.COLUMNS):
                tmpBoard = self.copyBoard(board)
                if self.is_legal_move(move, tmpBoard):
                    self.drop_piece_computer(move, tmpBoard, moveNumber)
                    result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, computerPlayer, humanPlayer, False, moveNumber + 1)
                    if result >= maxValue:
                        maxValue = result
                        bestMove = move
            return bestMove
        else:
            minValue = 1000000
            for move in range(0,self.COLUMNS):
                tmpBoard = self.copyBoard(board)
                if self.is_legal_move(move, tmpBoard):
                    self.drop_piece_computer(move, tmpBoard, moveNumber)
                    result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, humanPlayer, humanPlayer, True, moveNumber + 1)
                    if result <= minValue:
                        minValue = result
                        thismove = move
            return thismove
```

However, if you look closely when I recursively call the function back to the AI in the !maximizing player function I have:

```
result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, humanPlayer, humanPlayer, True, moveNumber + 1)
```

In words when a simulated human player was playing on a generic board to generate the ai move it was assuming that there were 2 human players, and thats why the halt would happen because you cannot have a game with 2 of the same player.

so changing:

```
result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, humanPlayer, humanPlayer, True, moveNumber + 1)
```

to this:

```
result = self.generate_move(tmpBoard, depth - 1, computerPlayer, humanPlayer, True, moveNumber + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `False` instead of `True` in the `if maximizingPlayer` block and `True` instead of `False` in the else clause for the second to last argument to the recursive calls to `generate_move` seems to fix the game.

i.e. Change False on line 33 of Minimax.py to True and change the True on line 44 to False.